# Replace boolean values with integers in numPy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am working on determining correlation for a set of data containing boolean values. The ideal situation would be to replace all instances of booleans with 1's and 0's. How can I most efficiently parse through my numPy array and replace these values? Bellow is what I have to work with and the output...

```
def findCorrelation(csvFileName):
    data = pd.read_csv(csvFileName)
    data = data.values
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
    npList = np.asarray(df)
    print npList
    print df.corr()
```

Output:

```
   [[320 True]
     [400 False]
     [350 True]
     [360 True]
     [340 True]
     [340 True]
     [425 False]
     [380 False]
     [365 True]]
    Empty DataFrame
    Columns: []
    Index: []
    Success
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: If your array is `arr`, then what you need is `arr.astype(int)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function you're looking for is `astype` ([documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html)).

Example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.asarray([[320, True], [400, False], [350, True], [360, True], [340, True], [340, True], [425, False], [380, False], [365, True]]).astype(int)

print (a)
```

Output:

```
[[320   1]
 [400   0]
 [350   1]
 [360   1]
 [340   1]
 [340   1]
 [425   0]
 [380   0]
 [365   1]]
```